# How to find power scaling of expressi0n containing ln?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

$y(x)=\frac{1}{\ln({\frac{a*x}{-\ln(1-b/x^2)}})}$

Can we tell what is the scaling behavior of $y(x)$ goes as $x^{(some-power)}$

$b/x^2$ is small

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions, they come out in the correct font and spacing.  So \ln x gives $\ln x$ as opposed to ln x which gives $ln x$

Comment: Second hint:  You can put \left( and \right) around something and they will get larger to enclose the something.  So \left( \frac{ \frac 12}3 \right ) gives $ \left(  \frac {\frac 12}3 \right )$ instead of (\frac{\frac 12}3) giving $(\frac{\frac 12}3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\frac b{x^2} \ll 1, -\ln(1-\frac b{x^2}) \approx \frac b{x^2}$  If you plug this in, you still won't get polynomial behavior for $y(x)$ because of the other $\ln$